# Illustrator:Why does the PDF version of my file show content I already deleted on the AI file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

I had a few random lines on my illustrator file so i Decided to delete them.

Now: When I open this file on illustrator, the lines are gone - perfect.
But when I saved this exact file as a PDF, then opened the PDF separately from illustrator these lines were back.

I went back to the original AI file to discover the lines weren't there. Then I saved it again as a PDF to discover they came back.

Why is the PDF showing lines which are CLEARLY not on the original AI file?

Comment: If you've re-exported the PDF from Illustrator, the lines shouldn't be showing up if they've been deleted. Try opening the file in Illustrator and viewing the file in Outline mode by pressing Ctrl/Cmd + Y. This will allow you to see any lines that may be hidden by other objects or effects.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've posted my above comment as an answer, so that future users will be able to access this information. If you would, please take the time to accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you've re-exported the PDF from Illustrator, the lines shouldn't be showing up if they've been deleted.

Try opening the file in Illustrator and viewing the file in Outline mode by pressing Ctrl/Cmd + Y. This will allow you to see any lines that may be hidden by other objects or effects